# Is there a set phrase for being polite to a person only when they are present?

Tags: pejorative-language, popular-refrains, proverbs, aphorism-requests

Is there a saying or proverb for when a person or group of people act politely and with respect towards a certain member of a group in front of a person of respect or elder, and then acts with disrespect and completely differently towards that same member of the group when the respected elder is not around? It involves being two-faced and a kiss-ass. 
"When the cat's away, the mice come out and play" isn't a good fit, yet has some elements of what I'm trying to describe. Is there a saying in another language that might work?

Comment: "When the cat's away..." refers to the bad behaviour phase without the elder. Presumably you're asking about the good behaviour? The "When the cat's in view..." phase? [Actually those five words sound like a good start if a rhyme can be found!]

Comment: So what's wrong with "two-faced"?

Comment: Depending on whether you approve or disapprove of such behavior in a particular case, you might refer to the person as being "socially graceful" or "a damned hypocrite."

Comment: there's some amount of *lip service*, but that doesn't quite fit.

Comment: also, shakespeare's **iago** played this role, but much more vengefully.

Answer (score 1):

If your audience consists of those conversant with classic American television, this type of behavior could be described as **being a regular Eddie Haskell** (or "acting like Eddie Haskell").  [Eddie Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Haskell) is an archetypal character from the classic early TV show "Leave It To Beaver" whose defining characteristic was exactly the type of behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest you combine an adjective denoting "two-faced" and a noun denoting "kiss-ass."

Adjectives for **two-faced** (besides "two-faced" itself):

> **beguiling**
>
> **deceptive**
>
> **backstabbing**
>
> **double-crossing**
>
> **lying**

Nouns denoting **kiss-ass** (besides "kiss-ass" itself):

> **sycophant**
>
> **flatterer**
>
> **bootlicker**
>
> **brownnoser**
>
> **toady**

Thus you can generate a variety of epithets, like:

> **Barry is such a backstabbing sycophant.**
>
> **I can't believe what a lying booklicker Sheila is**.
>
> **Don't be such a deceptive flatterer. Tell the boss how you really feel**.

Comment: **Back Stabbers** rated a video by the The O'Jays: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzTeLePbB08 See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backstabber

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Ireland but have lived for a long time in America and, incidentally just watched every episode ever made of Leave it to Beaver. The word that instantly pops into my head that describes him best is "smarmy".  I am honestly unsure as to the etymology of the word and also as to whether or not it is considered slang or not but, if dictionaries included pictures for every definition, Eddie Haskell would be right next to smarmy.

UPDATE:

I apologise as I misread the original post and what you were actually looking for.  I will see what I can find to that end.

In the meantime, check out these links and see if you don't agree that this words applies to Eddie.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).